# GoPro's denoising artifacts

Tags: video-quality, video-recording, gopro

When shooting a piano from overhead with a GoPro Hero10 Black,
the hands' skin texture and knuckle wrinkles are smoothed so much that it looks like a plastic mannequin.  It looks like what PhotoShop would do when denoising aggressively, or posterizing, or exporting to a low quality JPEG.

How can I make the gopro's output look better, even as realistic as that of an
ancient point-and-shoot Canon PowerShot Elph 330 HS, never mind as good as a modern four-thirds camera?

Here are 100% crops of video frames from
the GoPro (L) and the Canon (R),
taken with a wide range of settings and lighting.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I've tried adjusting the GoPro's ISO, resolution, frame rate, over/underexposure, H.264 vs HEVC, field of view, bit rate, and probably a few more things.